# How to use Cascade Soft Delete Trait in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-7

$inst = Institution::find($institution->id);
$campus = InstitutionCampusId::where('institution_campus_id.institution_id' , $institution->id);
$inst->delete();
$campus->delete();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cascading deletes are handled at the database-level, so when you set onDelete('cascade') in your migration, that translates to your database deleting any records attached by foreign key.

Soft deletes are handled by the application, so you'd either need to fire an event on the parent model and listen for it on the children or, in your parent model, bind the static::deleted() method in the boot method, and delete the relationships there.

I'm not sure if you could do something like:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function ($model) {
        // Probably lazy load these relationships to avoid lots of queries?
        $model->load([ 'relationshipOne', 'relationshipTwo', ]);

        $model->relationshipOne()->delete();
        $model->relationshipTwo()->delete();
    });
}
```

Or if you'd have to iterate over the related items:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function ($model) {
        $model->relationshipOne->each(function ($item) {
            $item->delete();
        });

        $model->relationshipTwo->each(function ($item) {
            $item->delete();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm almost sure the second example would be better as this would allow any static::delete binds on the foreign model to be run also. I just had an issue where the first example worked but did not fire my audit binds to log that all related rows had been deleted. ->each->delete() did the trick;

Answer (score -2):

add this trait in your model

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

add this in your migration it will add deleted at field in your table

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

Comment: This is just for soft delete, not for cascade delete.